# Reddit PHP SDK returns NULL on everything

Tags: php, sdk, reddit

I am using [Reddit PHP SDK](https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk) trying to create a bot. I created a new username for the bot.

I've created an app on reddit and added the client ID and secret key to `config.php`

These are the endpoints I'm using

```
static $ENDPOINT_STANDARD = 'http://www.reddit.com';
static $ENDPOINT_OAUTH = 'https://oauth.reddit.com';
static $ENDPOINT_OAUTH_AUTHORIZE = 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize';
static $ENDPOINT_OAUTH_TOKEN = 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token';
static $ENDPOINT_OAUTH_REDIRECT = 'http://localhost/reddit';
```

And this is `index.php`

```
require_once("reddit.php");
$reddit = new reddit('username', 'password');
var_dump($reddit->getUser());
```

This return `NULL`

```
$response = $reddit->getListing("technology", 5);
var_dump($response);
```

This also returns `NULL`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: From the docs: Before making requests to any of the methods of the Reddit SDK, you first need to instantiate a new OAuth 2 session by using your client id and client secret.

Comment: I already created an app on reddit and added the client id and secret key to `config.php`